# .Net Core 2.2 Azure reply url specified does not match reply urls configured for application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 Azure App registrations setup, one for testing, and one for live. 
The test setup works great and is configured to redirect to localhost, the live setup however gives me a "AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application..." error after entering my login information.

The appsettings.json configuration is as follows: (Ids removed)

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "https://myapplication.azurewebsites.net",
"CallbackPath": "/auth/sign-in",
}
```

The application has been published to Azure as myapplication.azurewebsites.net, and the App registration redirect URI is set to "https://myapplication.azurewebsites.net/auth/sign-in"

The Azure application is configured to use the app registration.

The live and localhost setups are identical besides replacing "localhost:5001" with "myapplication.azurewebsites.net", and the Ids for each app registration.

Other questions about this refer to the old Azure UI or advise to set the redirect URI, which I have already done.

Comment: I had this problem before and I found out that the browser caching was the one giving me this headache. I tested the prod version using incognito mode and it worked.

Comment: The domain in your appsettings.json should be "your tenant domain". Besides, regarding how to update your redirect url, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-redirect-uris-to-your-application

Answer (score 0):

As Jim said, enter the **domain of your tenant**, e.g. `contoso.onmicrosoft.com`.

Also, when you use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize` to send the sign in request, you could get the `redirect_uri` in the request url. Then compare it with the value in `Authentication` `Redirect URLs` of your App registered.

For more detials, refer to the article about [Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore).

Answer (score 0):

The resolution here was simply to restart the app service within Azure.
In the past when publishing .net MVC and WebForms projects, the app service restarted itself after the publish, it didn't do so with the .net core project which meant it was still running with an out-dated config.